# Postgresql9.6: Why 10 loops of parallel query done their work slower than 1 loop

Tags: postgresql, sql-execution-plan, postgresql-9.6

Postgres 9.6; Centos 6.7 ; 24 cores
BigTable1 contains 1,500,000,000 rows; weight 180GB.
max_worker_processes = 20 max_parallel_workers_per_gather = 12

Two tests done and compared:

1) When running explain analyze select count(*) from BigTable1;

We have “Workers Planned: 10” and query execution time is 448 sec.
EXPLAIN ANALYZE output is:

```
Parallel Seq Scan on BigTable1 (cost=0.00..20137165.46 rows=**177208946** width=0) (actual time=0.023..417798.820 rows=159481670 loops=10)
```

We see almost all the time spent for read and count the data in the BigTable1

2) When running the same query with defined set max_parallel_workers_per_gather = 0;

The execution time is 547 sec.

```
 Aggregate  (cost=38306668.21..38306668.22 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=547132.254..547132.255 rows=1 loops=1)
   ->  Append  (cost=0.00..34319310.77 rows=1594942978 width=0) (actual time=0.562..444920.155 rows=**1595067208** loops=1) 
        -> Seq Scan on category_data_prt_201702  (cost=0.00..34313881.12 rows=1594880512 width=0) (actual time=0.026..312120.207 rows=1594816703 loops=1)
```

The questions are:

- Why 10 loops done their work slower than 1 loop?
- Where the query without parallel did spend its time, i.e. what does the following mean:

```
 Aggregate  (cost=38306668.21..38306668.22 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=547132.254..547132.255 rows=1 loops=1)
   ->  Append  (cost=0.00..34319310.77 rows=**1594942978** width=0) (actual time=0.562..444920.155 rows=1595067208 loops=1)
```

- Why there is not those “Append / Aggregate “ sections in case of Parallel Query execution test?

Comment: Apparently your harddisk isn't fast enough to copy with 10 parallel threads. Doing a lot of stuff in parallel is not always faster then doing it one after the other

Comment: In addition to that, did you run the test several times? Maybe the database had to read more from disk the first time, and the second time the data were already in the file system cache.